# How to add add a record to a map in CameLIGO

Tags: smart-contracts, ligo

I'm using CameLIGO and want to add a record to a map. I keep getting this error:

```
Error: ligo: : Parse error in file "tmp-1lMUlWlg5fktI.ligo", line 21, characters 45-46, after "{" and before "}":
      8: <syntax error> {}
```

I can't figure out the correct structure for a record?

```
type ipfsHash = string
type artist = address
type artworkId = string

type artists_storage = (artist, ipfsHash) map
type artwork = {
  artist: artist;
  owner : address;
  ipfsArtworkAddress: string;
}

type artwork_storage = (artworkId, artwork) map

type action =
| Register of ipfsHash

let registerArtist (store, ipfsHash : artists_storage * ipfsHash) : artists_storage = 
  Map.update(Tezos.self_address : artist) (Some (ipfsHash)) store

// errors ->
let createArtwork (store, id, ihash : artwork_storage * artworkId * ipfsHash) : artwork_storage =
  Map.update(id: artworkId) (Some (artwork: {
    artist = Tezos.self_address;
    owner = Tezos.self_address;
    ipfsArtworkAddress = ihash;
  }) store

let main (p, artists: action * artists_storage) =
 let storage =
   match p with
   | Register h -> registerArtist (artists, h)
 in ([] : operation list), artists
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the corrected version of `createArtwork`:

```
let createArtwork (store, id, ihash : artwork_storage * artworkId * ipfsHash) : artwork_storage =
  Map.update (id : artworkId) (Some ({
    artist = Tezos.self_address;
    owner = Tezos.self_address;
    ipfsArtworkAddress = ihash;
  } : artwork)) store
```

You had switched place on the actual record and the type annotation (`: artwork`), and a parenthesis was missing. Also, in this case the type annotation on the record is not necessary: it is only necessary for empty lists, sets and maps AFAIK.

Comment: Yesss!! Thank you. I see now!